# How to insert query in wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a email subscription to my site and I want to insert to my Wordpress database so I can export the email listing. I already created table wp_email_subscription with 4 fields ID, name, email and date created. what will be the query for this? is there any wordpress database script to use?

Answer (score 17):

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_email_subscription (name, email, date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$date')"  );
```

This is if you want to insert values to your table. You do not have to use $wpdb->email_subscription for the prefix as it's the table you created yourself, otherwise, if you were inserting values to default WordPress tables you would prefer doing
$wpdb->users etc.

Comment: I know this answer is pretty old but you should always use the ``$wpdb`` method since it automatically escapes the values and avoids sql injection issues.

Answer (score 17):

Wordpress provides the `$wpdb` class of functions for interacting with the database.

To insert an email address you could do something like:

```
<?php 

  $wpdb->insert('wp_email_subscription', 
    array(
      'name'          => 'name',
      'address'       => 'name@email.com'
    ),
    array(
      '%s',
      '%s'
    ) 
  ); 

?>
```

More info on the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Answer (score 7):

you can go for

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('wp_email_subscription',array('name'=>$name,'email'=>$email),array('%s','%s'));
```

go through this for better understanding:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 2):

```
function insert($array = false)
{
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'email_subscription', $array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 global $wpdb

 $wpdb->insert('wp', array(
                        'email' => $_POST['email'],
                        'city'  =>   $_POST['city'],
                        'state' =>$_POST['state'],
                        'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
                       'mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
                       )
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'you_table_name';
$data = array('column1' => 'data one', 'column2' => 123);
$format = array('%s','%d');
$wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
```

All information you can read [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/)